# inductively construct a basis

Tags: group-theory

By a theorem of Lie–Kolchin, a connected solvable subgroup of $GL(V)$ has a common eigenvector on $V$.

Let $G$ be a connected, solvable subgroup of $GL_n$. Then, $G$ is conjugate to a subgroup of $T_n$ (upper triangular matrices).

In the proof, it says to apply the above theorem to inductively construct a basis with respect to
which $G$ is triangular.

I am not sure how to construct the basis. So I assume it holds for when $n = k$, then I show it holds for $k+1$ where the one more is the space generated by common eigenvector? Thank you.

Comment: This is an easy standard linear algebra exercise to deduce the existence of such a basis. This site is for research-level questions. [By the way, in your statement of the theorem, you omit to say that you're working over the complex numbers (or so), and that $V\neq 0$.]

Comment: Just a hint: look at the proof of the triangulability of all matrices (over the field of complex numbers).